# ¿Por qué no funciona el método Buffer.BlockCopy en este bucle? C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando generar un fichero de fuentes seleccionadas por el usuario. Para ello, parto del siguiente código:

```
foreach (DataRow drFuente in dtFonts.Rows)
                    {
                        string registro = ComunicacionesL.Registros.GenerarTF(oBalanza,  oConexion, drFuente, oLog);
                        //Aqui tenemos que obtener los bytes del stream builder
                        byte[] bytesRegistro = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registro);
                        int longitudArray = bytesRegistro.Length;
                        byte[] bRegistro = new byte[longitudArray];

                        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registro), 0, bRegistro, 0, longitudArray);
                        lstRegistros.Add(bRegistro);
                        //if (Convert.ToString(drFuente["Operacion"]) != DatosComunes.OPERACION_BAJA)
                        //    lstRegistros.AddRange(ComunicacionesL.Registros.GenerarLD_EnBytes(oBalanza, pulgadas, int.MinValue, drLogo, oLog));

                    }
```

El problema lo tengo con `System.Buffer.BlockCopy`. Cada fuente genera un fichero de distinto tamaño, pero suelen estar entre 3000 y 4000 bytes. Aunque no genera ningún error ni excepción, la aplicación se me queda frita. En cambio, si en vez de una longitud de 3000 o 4000, coloco 130 o 260, funciona sin problemas (pero sólo me copia 130 o 260 bytes, no el total). ¿Hay alguna manera de que `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` copie gran cantidad de bytes? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Respondo a la pregunta. La cuestión era que el programa sólo admite múltiplos de 130, por eso al ser en tamaño en bytes un número que no es múltiplo de 130, falla.
Ya sabéis, el debuggeo hace milagros. Un saludo